# Visual Studio: Make view code default

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to make Visual Studio show the code of a control / form by default instead of the designer? I tend not to be a fan of the designers as they add bloat.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but the prev answers don't exactly match my case.
So with my VS2017, working mostly on VB.net forms, I chose "Microsoft Visual Basic Editor".
(I don't have "CSharp Editor" in the list)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Right-click on a file and select "Open With..."

Select "CSharp Editor" and then click "Set as Default".

Answer (score 15):

Decorate your class with [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")], e.g.:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
public class MySpecialButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is better solution, when you want to set it only for one class, not as GLOBAL setting. Funny thing is, that it doesn't work if you write [DesignerCategory("")] and add using System.ComponentModel.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, otherwise you lose "View Code" and the ability to use the designer across the board.  This let's you do it on a granular level (such as for inherited user controls).

Answer (score 6):

I like having my forms open up in Design View, but I made a partial class file which had only code and Visual Studio wanted to open it in Design View all the time.  To prevent Visual Studio from realizing that a specific source file can be loaded by Designer, look at the csproj file for the Compile Include tag of the appropriate source file and remove the SubType tag underneath it.

Comment: also:  <SubType>Code</SubType>

Answer (score 6):

I came across this issue myself recently and the above solutions did not solve my issue. I needed to go into `Tools | Options` and change the settings for `HTML Designer` to `Enable HTML designer` and select `Start pages in: Source View`.

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: I had to go to WebForm Designer, but this essentially did it for me