# VS2008 Open .cs file in Code View instead of Design View

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration

I am writing a windows service in VS2008 - c#.  When I double click on a .cs file in the Solution Explorer it opens in Design View by default (Windows Form Designer).  Is there a way to configure it to open in Code View (Text Editor) by default as this is driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768?sort=votes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Make view code default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768/visual-studio-make-view-code-default)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right-click on the .cs file and select "Open With".  When the dialog opens, pick "CSharp Editor", and click the "Set as Default" button.  All the form files will now open in source editor.  You can always go back and pick "CSharp Form Editor" when you want to go back.

Answer (score 0):

Non-default method -> right-click and select "view code"...

For a default method, a quick Google search turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768?sort=votes) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Mr. Brownstone - Yes, another brilliantly simple suggestion. :)