# Visual Studio: Make view code default using attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I know how to [configure VS 2008 to open windows forms controls in code instead of the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768?sort=votes). But I think I have seen a way I could do this with an attribute I could decorate the desired controls with. Does anyone know its name? This is especailly usefull if you want some controls to be opened in the designer and some in the c# code view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have found where you already seen that: the [Brian Ensink's blog](http://www.brianensink.com/blog/post/2009/04/02/The-DesignerCategory-attribute.aspx). You can use the [DesignerCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designercategoryattribute.aspx) attribute to mark class in order to choose how they are opened:

- If you inherit a class from System.Windows.Form, it will be open by the designer view.
- If you add the [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")] attribute, it will be open by the code view.

Answer (score 8):

The magic line you seek is:

[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]

Just put that before your control-derived type and kiss that useless designer goodbye.

Answer (score -1):

This option is available in Visual studio  2010

1. Tools > Options
2. check show all settings
3. html Designer
   4 select Source View
4. restart Visual Studio

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is an answer to my question.