# Overriding Designer attribute in derived class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a class that inherits the built in `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` class. According to the metadata of the `Panel` class, it has an attribute named `Designer`. I am assuming this is what is causing my derived class to open in the form designer by default, rather than the code view. Is there a way I can override this attribute so that the file opens in code view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. Thanks goes to [Visual Studio: Make view code default using attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789603/visual-studio-make-view-code-default-using-attribute?rq=1).

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply right-click and select "View Code" in VS, either in the Solution Explorer or in the designer view.

Comment: This is true, although I'd like to change the default behaviour, if possible.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do that.