# Visual Studio 2010 "Open With..." is missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration

I'm trying to change Visual Studio to open my code instead of designer by default. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768/visual-studio-make-view-code-default) tells me to right click on a file and go to "Open With..."

However, when I try to right click on a file in my solution explorer I have no "Open With..." option. I'm not sure if this is caused by an extension (I have the CodeRush Xpress, VSCommands, Productivity Power tools, and VCS tools for SVN, Git, and Hg), or what, but I would like to be able to configure what my files open with.

Where do I need to go to either get the menu option back or change these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context menu can be modified.  If you haven't heavily customized your command bars and menus then a full reset is wise.  Tools + Import/Export, "Reset all settings" radio button.

Or fix the context menu.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab, click the "Context menu" radio button.  Select the "Project and Solution Context Menu | Item" option from the combobox.  Click the Add Command button.

Comment: Ahah! That worked perfect. The "Open With..." option is in the view category. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN link might help you:

[How to: Change or Add a Default Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy2sthf1.aspx)

It's not the most intuitive method, but from the link:

1. On the File menu in Visual Studio, choose Open and then select File.
2. In the Open File dialog box, select a file of the type you want to change.
3. Still in the Open File dialog box, click the down arrow next to the Open button, and then select Open With.
4. In the Open With dialog box, choose an editor from the Select a program to open list.
5. Click the Set as Default button and then click the Open button to open the file.

Comment: Unfortunately that only changes the behavior for opening files from File > open. Double click still opens the .vb files with design instead of code view.

Comment: Ack, sorry then. I thought they were tied to the same settings.

Comment: I would have thought so, too. Unfortunately, Microsoft didn't :P