# Disable Design View for C# Class in VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My C# project displays classes in the Solution Explorer some with the Designer View and some with the normal code editor:

> [image: Desginer View]   AND   [image: Code Editor]

I Would like to make them all open with the code editor!

I went in the .csproj file and I noticed that for the classes marked as designer, I get a
`<SubType>Component</SubType>` tag. If I remove it manually, VS automatically re-add it to the item.

How to solve it? I searched but did not found anything usefull..

EDIT 1: I forgot to mention that this is a Console Application

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399768/visual-studio-make-view-code-default) help you?